# Plugin for making UI changes in Kibana

Tags: plugins, kibana-5

Is their some available plugin that can help make UI changes like Logo, text on UI interface or some good guide to create kibana plugin.

Answer (score 1):

This guide is a bit out of date, but it might get you going anyways: https://www.timroes.de/2015/12/02/writing-kibana-4-plugins-basics (even though it was written for kibana 4, the basics worked all right for me even in kibana 6)
Maybe you can change the logo and some texts with the help of a hack.js in your plugin